# How to check is an object is being touched by a spherecast?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to see if i can trigger actions in an object based on whether a spherecast is touching it, Ideally I want to do this via a script attached to the object that's being touched by the spherecast component, initially I was trying something like this using OnCollisionEnter.

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
    {
        //Touched = SphereCaster.collider.gameObject.GetComponent(UnityEngine.PlayerLoop.FixedUpdate);
        if (col.gameObject.name == "Sphere Caster")
        {
            dontShow();
        }
    }
```

Any ideas on how to register that the Sphere Collider is touching an object?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what do you mean by "register that the Sphere Collider is touching an object"? Could you add more details to your questions and determine what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You can, but you have to approach the problem from a different line of thinking. When you are casting you are not actually introducing a "physical" object that is interacting with your scene, but rather querying the physics engine for objects that are along the path.

Instead you have to rely on the results that the cast returns to you and from there apply the necessary actions. [`Physics.SphereCast`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.SphereCast.html) returns a bool that siginfies that something was touched and that `out RaycastHit hitInfo` contains information on the object. Depending on your object you then may find the script that contains the function that you want to call.

Here is an example of how this might look like:

```cs
if (Physics.SphereCast(origin, radius, direction, out RaycastHit hit, 10))
{
  hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<YourScript>().YourFunction();
}
```